# Static notification in Android application [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3, push-notification, ane

A few days ago I've been looking for a solution to using a Push Notification, but I have not found ANE's functional for the problem.

I'm finalizing an application in the ActionScript3 language, and I only found something related to Cloud Messaging, which is something much more advanced than I need.

I try to present a simple Push Notification to the user, static, only with Title and Message. However, I could not find ways to find such a resource.

Does anyone using the ActionScript language have achieved the feat of using Push Notifications without Google's Cloud Messaging feature? Waiting for answers :)

---

I went after explanatory projects on GitHub, but 60% of ANE's content is cloud-centric or not working. In addition to having some I'm not targeting the AS3 language.

Comment: https://github.com/marpies/onesignal-ane

Answer (score 0):

why you don't try **local** notification?
in this ANE you can display local notifications with only a few lines of code

I have the same project and use this ANE, it works like a charm
https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Notifications